# Azure AD B2C: Uploading custom policies via github actions

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, github-actions

I am trying to upload a few custom policies(base, extension and RP) to Azure B2C using github actions that would use an azure service principal(client id and secret), tenant id and subscription id. I have used this github action:

```
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-azure-ad-b2c-trustframework-policy
```

When the action executes in my pipeline, I get this error:

```
Action failed: client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret
```

The github secrets section of the repository has CLIENT_SECRET defined like this:

[image]

There is another variable called AZURE_CREDENTIALS that has a JSON like this:

```
 {
   "clientId": "my-clientId",
   "clientSecret": "my-clientSecret",
   "tenantId": "my-tenantId",
   "subscriptionId": "my-subscriptionId"
 }
```

Any clues on what I am missing? Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Post your workflow yaml, otherwise it's difficult to help  you

Comment: The workflow yml was posted in the question: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-azure-ad-b2c-trustframework-policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/77725/azure-ad-b2c-uploading-custom-policies-via-github.html